# calling std::future::get repeatedly

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I want to construct an object `Delay` asynchronously and then (from another thread) repeatedly call a function `foo` from that object.

```
struct Delay {
    Delay(int d) {
        sleep(d);
    }
    void foo() { }
};

struct Test {
    Test() {
        x = async(std::launch::async,
                  [&]() {return std::make_unique<Delay>(4);});
    }
    void run() { x.get()->foo(); }
    std::future<std::unique_ptr<Delay>> x;
};

int main() {
    auto t = Test();
    // do other stuff...
    t.run();
    t.run(); // throwing an instance of 'std::future_error',  "No associated state"
    return 0;
}
```

However, obviously, the second time x.get() gets called, an exception is thrown.

What is the recommended way to deal with such a situation? Using a flag as shown below seems like a hack. Is there a better way?

```
bool is_set = false;
std::unique_ptr<Delay> ptr;
void run_ptr() {
    if (!is_set) {
        ptr = x.get();
        is_set = true;
    }
    ptr->out();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_future` is the recommended way to deal with such a situation.

It can be constructed by moving from a future, and supports multiple readers of its state.  It is a distinct object because the one-deliver future had certain performance improvements, and because it is so trivial to make a shared future if you need it.

Simply change the type of `x` to `shared_future<std::unique_ptr<Delay>>` and you are done.

Note, however, that in your above case the `unique_ptr` layer is mostly pointless.  Probably in your real problem it is not.